# How have I incorrectly computed $\int \frac{x^{2}+4}{x(x-1)^{2}} dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

My work:
$\displaystyle \int \frac{x^{2}+4}{x(x-1)^{2}}dx$$ =\int \frac{A}{x} dx+\int \frac{B}{x-1}dx +\int \frac{C}{(x-1)^{2}}dx$

$x^{2} + 4 = A(x-1)^{2} + Bx(x-1) + C(x) $

$x^2 + 4 = x^{2}(A+B) + x(-2A+C) + (A-B)$

equating coefficients:

$1 = A + B $

$0 = - 2A + C $

$4 = A - B$

then

$1 - B = A$

so

$4 = 1 - B - B$

$\frac{-3}{2} = B$

and

$4 = A - \frac{-3}{2}$

$\frac{5}{2} = A$

then

$0 = - 2(\frac{5}{2}) + C$

$0 = - 5 + C$

$5 = C$

plugging A, B, and C back into the integral I got:
$= \frac{5}{2}ln|x| - \frac{3}{2}ln|x - 1| - 5ln|x - 1| + C$
wolfram state this is wrong. What have I done wrong here?
Thank you

Comment: Why do you get a logarithm with the fraction involving $C$ ?

Comment: There's a trick to partial fractions.  In $\forall x ~:~ x^{2} + 4 = A(x-1)^{2} + Bx(x-1) + Cx$ plug in the roots, $x=0$ then $x=1$.  You get $4 = A(-1)^2$ then $1^2 + 4 = C$.  If there hadn't been a multiplicity root then you wouldn't have gotten $B$ right away as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$x$ has a $-B$ coefficient as well, so $0 = - 2A - B - C$.  And $4 = A-B$ should just be $4=A$.  It looks like you mistakenly did $Bx(x-1) = Bx^2 - B$ instead of $Bx^2 - Bx$.

Here's a handy tip for dealing with partial fraction decompositions.

When you get to $x^{2} + 4 = A(x-1)^{2} + Bx(x-1) + C(x) $, you can exploit the fact that this is an **identity in the variable $x$**.  In other words, this equation is **true no matter what $x$ is**.  So, you can plug in "helpful" values of $x$ to determine the values of $A$, $B$, $C$.

For example, if $x=0$ then $0^2 + 4 = A(-1)^2$, which gives $A = 4$.  Plugging in $x=1$ immediately gives you $C$.  Then since you have $A$ and $C$ you can plug in any other value of $x$ to get $B$.  No need to mess around with systems of equations.

Comment: When finding the constants $A$, $B$, and $C$, why do you include the numerator on the LHS? I've always done it without the numerator and it has always worked; i.e., I just do PFD on $\frac{1}{x(x-1)^2}$. Unfortunately, for this problem it did not work. Why is that? Have I just been lucky in the past when using PFD my way?

Comment: @user193319, you include the numerator because you're doing the partial fraction decomposition of $\dfrac{x^2 + 4}{x(x-1)^2}$, not $\dfrac1{x(x-1)^2}$.  If ignoring the numerator got you the right answer in the past, it's either a massive coincidence or another error was made elsewhere in the process that balanced it out.

Answer (score 3):

$$\int \frac{1}{(x-1)^2} dx \neq \ln|x-1|+C$$

$$\int \frac{1}{(x-1)^2} dx= \int (x-1)^{-2} dx =\frac{(x-1)^{-1}}{-1}+C=-\frac{1}{x-1}+C$$